# How to fix minimum value for Edit Text when the minimum can be a signed number in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to fix minimum and maximum value in my EditText. I used InputFilter and for the maximum value which is "100" it's already working but for the minimum that should be "-100" my edit text don't allow me to put the "-" before entering my integer. How can I fix it please?

here is the class

```
package ws.splash.project.model;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {
private int min, max;

public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
    this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
    this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    try {
        double input = Double.valueOf(dest.toString() + source.toString());
        if (isInRange(min, max, input))
            return null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
    return "";
}

private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, double c) {
    return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
}
}
```

and this is how I call it:

```
       editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("-100","100")});
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you show your java code or xml related to question ?

Comment: how are you creating `EdiText` in XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `numberSigned` as `inputType` to input `-`

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

And change your filter like below to handle negative

```
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    try {
        String newVal = dest.toString().substring(0, dstart) + dest.toString().substring(dend);

        newVal = newVal.substring(0, dstart) + source.toString() + newVal.substring(dstart);

        //Add this line to allow Negative values
        if(newVal.equalsIgnoreCase("-") && min < 0)
            return null;

        int input = Integer.parseInt(newVal);
        if (isInRange(min, max, input))
            return null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: I did already but when I do                                                                           `editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("-100","100")});`                  It works like I putted 0 as minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in xml
`android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"`

Or else you can add in Activity class as follows

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```